# How to install NATS CLI Tool in windows 10

Tags: nats.io, nats-streaming-server

I have up and running NATS server with docker in my windows machine.

I want to install the nats CLI Tool as well in my windows machine.

In the documentation it is only mentioned about Mac and Linux.
https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/clients

Answer (score 5):

I installed the application with Go. Additionally, you can install by running the following command:

'go install github.com/nats-io/natscli/nats@latest'

More information can be found at https://github.com/nats-io/natscli#installation-via-go-install.

Comment: does this require system restart? cause i installed it using this command but still the same error `'nats' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 5):

Just download `nats-0.0.34-windows-amd64.zip` from [natscli release page](https://github.com/nats-io/natscli/releases) and extract `nats.exe` wherever you want.

Comment: the nats-server is already installed but it does not support `nats-pub`,`nats-sub`, he needs to run `nats-pub`, `nats-sub` commands using `nats-cli`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Powershell 7.* and install it
2. Open notepad++ or notepad
3. Add the lines:

   listen: 192.168.1.121:4223
   #replace with your own ip address and port of choice
   authorization: {
   token: "your secret token here"
   #you can remove the whole authorization section if you want no security
   }
4. Save the file as nats.config to where the nats-server.exe executable is located
5. Open notepad++ or notepad again
6. Paste the following lines

   function Stop-Remove-Nats-Service {
   param($serviceObject)
   $name = $serviceObject.Name
   Write-Output("$($name) found")
   Stop-Service -Name $name
   Remove-Service -Name $name
   }

   function Install-Nats-Service{
   $currentLocation = "$(Get-Location)\nats-server.exe -c $(Get-Location)\nats.config"
   New-Service -BinaryPathName $currentLocation -Name "NatsServer"    -DisplayName "NATS Server" -StartupType "Automatic" -Description "NATS Streaming Server Service" | Start-Service
   }

   $service = Get-Service -Name "NatsServer"

   if($service -eq $null){
   Write-Output "Creating Service"
   #install if there is nothing
   Install-Nats-Service
   }else{
   Write-Output "Removing the existing service."
   Stop-Remove-Nats-Service $service
   Write-Output "Ovewriting existing service."
   Install-Nats-Service
   }
7. Save the file as nats-installer.ps1 to where the nats-server.exe is located
8. Open powershell 7
9. Navigate to where nats-server.exe is located.
10. Type .\nats-installer.ps1 (you might see an error at first but just ignore it as it looks for the existing service name and making sure to remove it before installing a new one)